# Prolog - turning of a list into a list of fact

Tags: python-3.x, prolog, swi-prolog

I start SWI-prolog, in Python, with the command:

```
subprocess.call("(source ~/.bash_profile && swipl -s planner.pl b a c b a table )", shell=True)
```

The script started is a planner:

```
 :- initialization (main).
    :- dynamic on/2.

%facts
on(a,b).
on(b,c).
on(c,table).

r_put_on(A,B) :-
     on(A,B).
r_put_on(A,B) :-
     not(on(A,B)),
     A \== table,
     A \== B,
     clear_off(A),       
     clear_off(B),
     on(A,X),
     retract(on(A,X)),
     assert(on(A,B)),
     assert(move(A,X,B)).

% Means there is space on table 
clear_off(table). 

% Means already clear
clear_off(A) :- not(on(_X,A)).

clear_off(A) :-
     A \== table,
     on(X,A),
     clear_off(X),      
     retract(on(X,A)),
     assert(on(X,table)),
     assert(move(X,A,table)).

do(Glist) :-
      valid(Glist),
      do_all(Glist,Glist).

valid(_).      


do_all([G|R],Allgoals) :-
     call(G),
     do_all(R,Allgoals),!.

do_all([G|_],Allgoals) :-          
     achieve(G),
     do_all(Allgoals,Allgoals).

do_all([],_Allgoals).              

achieve(on(A,B)) :-
     r_put_on(A,B).

main :-
    current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
    format('Called with ~q~n', [Argv]),
    parse the list
    listing(on), listing(move),
    halt.
main :-
    halt(1).
```

I need to parse the input parameters " c b b a a table" in a list of: " **[on(c,b),on(b,a),on(a,table)]**" in order to be executed from the rule **do** (e.g. do([on(c,b),on(b,a),on(a,table)])). 
The format print me this: `Called with [on,b,a,c,b,a,table]`

I'm not an expert of Prolog and I am really stuck right now, I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're almost there:

```
:- initialization (main).

main :-
    current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
    parse(Argv, Parsed),
    format('Called with ~q~n', [Parsed]),
    halt(1).

parse([], []).
parse([X,Y|Argv], [on(X,Y)|Parsed]) :- parse(Argv, Parsed).
```

Once saved in a file named `argv.pl`, I have these results:

```
$ swipl argv.pl a b c d
Called with [on(a,b),on(c,d)]
```

That is, arguments pairs have been realized, and the 'program' terminated.
There is no error handling, passing an odd number of arguments, I get a warning:

```
$ swipl argv.pl a b c
Warning: /home/carlo/test/prolog/argv.pl:1: Initialization goal failed
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.7.7-2-gd842bce)
etc etc...
```

Anyway, I think your `main`, after a successful parse/2, should `retractall(on(_,_))` and then `maplist(assertz,Parsed)`.